# Tool to convert a groff ms document to HTML

Tags: html, document-converter, documentation-generator, file-converter

I'm looking for a tool for converting [groff ms](https://linux.die.net/man/7/groff_ms) documents to HTML.

In particular, I would like the generated HTML to produce hyperlinks from each entry in the Table of Contents to the section in the page, and hyperlinks from references in the text to their entries in the bibliography. However, these are not hard requirements.

(FYI, I already looked at [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). pandoc supports converting to roff ms, but not *from* roff ms, which is what I want.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just failed to look in the [man page for groff](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/groff_man.7.html).

groff can be converted to HTML or XHTML by using the `-T` option: `-T html` for HTML output, and `-T xhtml` for XHTML output.

This will work for all groff macros, not just the ms macros.